# If $a+b=1$, show that $a^{4b^2} + b^{4a^2} \leq 1$

Tags: inequality

If $a+b=1$, show that $a^{4b^2} + b^{4a^2} \leq 1$. It's given that $a,b \in \mathbb{R^+}$.

I couldn't get the equality case actually. I couldn't get a rigorous way to get the equality case.

> > **EDIT: New method**
> >     For the inequality, WLOG assume $a>b$.
> >     Then $a^{4b^2} + b^{4a^2} \leq a^{4a^2} + b^{4a^2} \leq (a+b)^{4a^2} \leq 1$

Is it correct?

Thanks a lot StackExchangers!!

Comment: $a=b=1/2$, but $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}^+$?

Comment: Same question (with active bounty): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2176571/if-ab-1-so-a4b2b4a2-leq1.

Comment: I have edited it

Comment: I do not understand your "expansion method", but I assume that it fails because the exponents  are not integers.

Comment: @MartinR O, okay, true that.