# Rotation Inequality Conjecture

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality, rotations

*Note: This post has been reworked to be more readable*

While writing up a proof for [another post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2176571/269764), I have stumbled across a conjecture which seems true concerning rotations, which is as follows:

---

let $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ and $g(x)=1-x$. It is clear that $f(x)$ is greater on the interval $\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$, which has diameter $1$. We now rotate both curves $45^{\circ}$ counter-clockwise about the origin, and get two curves $f^*(x)$ and $g^*(x)$.

*Without finding an explicit form for $f^*$ and $g^*$*,

1. How can we prove that $f^*$ will still be greater than $g^*$ on some interval of diameter $1$
2. Can we determine this interval will be $(0,1)$?

More generally, what can we say about these questions when $f$ and $g$ are arbitrary curves (that may or not be functions before, during, or after rotation)? Will the length of the interval where $f$ exceeds $g$ be the same as the length of the interval where $f^*$ exceeds $g^*$?

---

The following image illustrates this, where orange is $g(x)=1-x$ and purple is $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$.
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by rotate $f$? Rotate the graph of $f$? Compose it with a rotation (in this case, what is a rotation on an interval?)?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri I realized I worded this is a confusing way. Yes, I *think* I mean "rotate the graph". I added an animation for better understanding since I am not great with the terminology here

Comment: So the rotation is about the origin? In any case, I feel it's important to point out that after the rotation the resulting curves may no longer be graphs of a function over the interval defined by their projection onto the $x$-axis.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Yes, around the origin. Sorry for the ambiguity! And yes, I realize the curves might not be functions. I ought to change the wording later (I cannot right now, and must go for a bit)

Comment: Well, $f^\star$ is not necessarily a function.

Comment: What is the "*conjecture*" that you mention twice, but never spell out?

Comment: @dxiv I have reworked my post to fix this. I was a bit rushed in writing the first iteration.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe I have reworked my post and addressed more explicitly now that $f^*$ need not be a function

Comment: Do you mean $45^\circ$ **counter**clockwise? If you go clockwise, $1-x$ goes vertical.

Comment: @WB-man *sigh* yep. The amount of typos I have made on this thing has made this comment section a nightmare

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, $f^*$ and $g^*$ are not necessarily functions after rotation. For example, consider the upper semicircle $y = \sqrt{1-x^2}$; *any* amount of rotation will cause it to no longer be a function.$\newcommand{\degs}{^\circ}
\newcommand{\cut}{\, \backslash \,}
\newcommand{\AND}{\ {\rm{\small{AND}}}\ }
\newcommand{\OR}{{\ \rm{\small{OR}}}\ }
\newcommand{\NOT}{\ {\rm{\small{NOT}}}\ }
\newcommand{\Implies}{\Rightarrow}
\newcommand{\If}{\Leftarrow}
\newcommand{\Iff}{\Leftrightarrow}
\newcommand{\x}{\times}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}} \newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}} \newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}} \newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}} \newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand{\E}{\operatorname{\rm{\small{E}}}}
\renewcommand{\Re}{\operatorname{Re}} \renewcommand{\Im}{\operatorname{Im}}
\newcommand{\dash}{\textrm{-}}
\newcommand{\der}{\partial}
\newcommand{\del}{\nabla}
\newcommand{\inv}{{\sim}}
\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}
\newcommand{\dedent}{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}$

However, we really do *need* the rotated curves to be functions if we want a notion of "above" and "below" to make sense. To see what I mean, let $f$ denote the upper unit semicircle I defined earlier, and let $g$ be identically zero on $[-1,\ 1]$. If we rotate them both clockwise we get the following:
[image]

In the red zone, the rotated $f^*$ has no $g^*$ underneath, leaving the comparison undefined.

So we need to ensure that $f^*$ and $g^*$ are well-defined functions. To do so, we need to impose some special conditions onto both $f$ and $g$. I don't know what the bare minimum *necessary* conditions are, but I do have a reasonably broad set of *sufficient* conditions that work. I will state them as part of the following proposition which, I think, is the essential gist of what you're wanting to prove:

> **Proposition:** Let $\Delta\theta$ be an angle in the open interval $(0,\ \pi/2)$, and let $f$ and $g$ be differentiable functions on the closed interval $[a,b]$ such that the following hold:
>
> - $f(a) = g(a) \AND f(b) = g(b)$,
> - $f(x) \geq g(x)$ for all $x \in [a,b]$,
> - $f'(x),\ g'(x) < \cot \Delta\theta$ for all $x \in [a,b]$.
>
> Then the counterclockwise rotations $f^*$ and $g^*$ by $\Delta\theta$ exist on the shifted interval $[a^*, b^*]$ (to be computed later) and satisfy $f^*(x) \geq g^*(x)$ on it.

For ease of presentation, this proposition is restricted to counterclockwise rotations, but the more general version for *clockwise* rotations is stated similarly to this one.

The key condition I imposed is that the derivatives of both $f$ and $g$ must be bounded by the cotangent of the rotation angle. To see the intuitive reason I did this, I pictured the rotation being a rotation of the *axes* instead of the *curves*. In that case, the question of whether the rotated curves will satisfy the vertical line test becomes equivalent to asking whether any line of the form
$$ y = (\cot \Delta\theta) x + b $$
intersects any one *un*rotated curve *twice*.

With that I'll dive into the proof of the Proposition.

(Note: every step may not be perfectly rigorous, but I think it works pretty well, and it's probably briefer than a thorough proof.)

---

The first thing we need to show is that $f^*$ and $g^*$ are well-defined functions. To do that, let's suppose that they're *not*. In that case the rotations fail the vertical line test, or equivalently, there exists a line
$$ y = (\cot \Delta\theta)x + b $$
that intersects either $f$ or $g$ twice. Assume without loss of generality that $f$ is guilty of this (the logic is the same for $g$). Let's call the two $x$-values of the two intersection points $\alpha$ and $\beta$. In that case the two points $\big(\alpha,\ f(\alpha) \big)$ and $\big(\beta,\ f(\beta) \big)$ must lie on a line with slope $\cot \Delta\theta$. Therefore
$$ \frac{f(\beta) - f(\alpha)}{\beta - \alpha} = \cot \Delta\theta $$
Then by the Mean Value Theorem, there must exist some $c$ between $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $f'(c) = \cot \Delta\theta$. This contradicts our assumption that $f'(x) < \cot \Delta\theta$ for all $x \in [a,b]$. $\checkmark$

Now we prove that the rotations still preserve the order. Consider any $x^* \in [a^*, b^*]$. We want to show $f^*(x^*) \geq g^*(x^*)$. Now the points $\big(x^*, f^*(x^*) \big)$ and $\big(x^*, g^*(x^*) \big)$ correspond to two points $\big(x_f, f(x_f) \big)$ and $\big(x_g, g(x_g) \big)$ in *un*rotated space. The statement $f^*(x) \geq g^*(x)$ is equivalent to saying that $x_f \geq x_g$

i.e. $f^*(x^*)$ is above $g^*(x^*)$ if and only if the corresponding point $\big(x_f, f(x_f) \big)$ is *upslope* from $\big(x_g, g(x_g) \big)$.

To prove it, suppose not. Suppose $x_f < x_g$. Then the two points $\big(x_f, f(x_f) \big)$ and $\big(x_g, g(x_g) \big)$ lie on a line of slope $\cot \Delta\theta$ and so
$$ \frac{g(x_g) - f(x_f)}{x_g - x_f} = \cot \Delta\theta $$
Now we assumed that $f(x) \geq g(x)$ for any $x$, so that means $f(x_g) \geq g(x_g)$. Hence
$$ \frac{f(x_g) - f(x_f)}{x_g - x_f} \geq \frac{g(x_g) - f(x_f)}{x_g - x_f} = \cot \Delta\theta $$
So by the Mean Value Theorem we again have a $c$ between $x_f$ and $x_g$ such that $f'(c) \geq \cot \Delta\theta$. A contradiction. $\checkmark$

---

And lastly a note on how to compute $a^*$ and $b^*$. We can treat a point $(x,y)$ on the plane as the complex number $x+yi$. If we want to rotate that point about the origin by $\Delta\theta$ radians (either positive or negative), we simply multiply:
$$ x^* + y^*i = (x+yi)e^{\theta i} $$
which yields
$$ x^* + y^*i = x \cos \Delta\theta - y \sin \Delta\theta + (y \cos \Delta\theta + x \sin \Delta\theta)i $$
Substituting
\begin{align}
x &= a,\ b \\
y &= f(a),\ f(b)
\end{align}
respectively and taking the real part will give $a^*$ and $b^*$.

For your particular $f$ and $g$:
\begin{align}
f(x) &= \sqrt{1-x^2} \\
g(x) &= 1-x
\end{align}
on the interval $[0,1]$ I get $a^*$ and $b^*$:
\begin{align}
a^* &= \Re \left(i \cdot e^{\pi/4 i} \right) = \Re \left(e^{3\pi/4 i} \right) = \cos(3\pi/4) = -\sqrt{2}/2 \\
b^* &= \Re \left(1 \cdot e^{\pi/4 i} \right) = \cos(\pi/4) = \sqrt{2}/2
\end{align}
yielding an interval length of $\sqrt{2}$ which is expected since that is the length of the diagonal of $y = 1-x$ on $[0,1]$.

Comment: OH, how could I be so dumb as to not understand why $f^*$ and $g^*$ must be functions. This clears everything up so much! I'll read through this a few times to make sure I grasp everything and it answers everything adequately before accepting. Again, thank you so much!

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen: No problem. Glad it helps. This was a fun problem for me to work. It's often interesting when algebra, calculus, and geometry collide.

Comment: How does $\cot \theta$ come into this? Is there some geometric argument you could show?

Comment: I'm not sure how it relates to rotating the axes.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen: "Rotating the axes" is perhaps a poor way to make my point. I just meant that instead of rotating the *curves* we could think of rotating the *vertical line*.
![Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muoQx.png)

You can see that every part of the curve of slope *greater* than $\cot\Delta\theta$ (the orange part) will turn back on itself when rotated counter-clockwise by $\Delta\theta$. The role of cotangent is to allow us to relate $\Delta\theta$ (angle) to derivatives (slopes). $\cot \Delta\theta$ is the maximum allowable slope our curves can have at any point.

Comment: Ok, I've now stared at that diagram for about 5 minutes and I think I get where $\cot \Delta \theta$ comes from geometrically, and I am really trying to understand it. I cannot thank you enough for your time, this is really fascinating stuff and I am simply amazed with how quickly you answered earlier! I haven't yet figured out how to prove the existence of the red point with slope $\cot \Delta \theta$ for each $\Delta \theta$ (looks like mean value theorem under certain conditions?) but if I understand correctly the red point, when the function is rotated counter-clockwise by $\Delta \theta$,

Comment: will land on the $x$-axis and thus everything below it will have to start rotating "inwards" again and "turn back on itself" in your words. The cotangent enters this geometrically, as $\cot \Delta \theta = y/x = m$ where $m$ is the slope. Since you seem to understand this better than I, how do I prove the existence of a point with slope $\cot \Delta \theta$?? It seems to me a simple result of the Mean Value Theorem... is this correct?

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen: I may not quite follow your reasoning, but I don't think you need to employ the MVT to prove the function $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ has a red point for any rotation angle you choose. I think it's pretty clear from the picture that the derivative $f'$ covers all possible slopes $(-\infty, \infty)$. If you want a slope $m$, just let $x$ get sufficiently close to either $1$ or $-1$. Since the range of $f'$ is all real numbers, there must be a point $x$ for which $f'(x) = \cot \Delta\theta$ no matter what $\Delta\theta$ we choose.