# About the inequality $rx^{r-1}\left(\sqrt{xy}-y\right)>x^{r}-y^{r}$ for $x>y>0$ and $r<0$

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis

In my book (Dictionnary of Inequalities ed 2 by Peter Bullen) we have p:27

If $x>y>0$ and $r<0$ then :

### $$rx^{r-1}\left(x-y\right)>x^{r}-y^{r}>ry^{r-1}\left(x-y\right)$$

The above inequality is easy dividing by $x-y$ and using Hermite-Hadamard inequality .

Now I ask for a refinement of it :

If $x>y>0$ and $r<0$ then :

### $$rx^{r-1}\left(\sqrt{xy}-y\right)>x^{r}-y^{r}\tag{I}$$

I have two question :

How to show $(I)$ ?

What is the limit for $x\to \infty$ (RHS-LHS in $(I)$)?

Thanks for all your reply and your effort in this sense .

Comment: How did you come up with that inequality? Why do you think that it holds? Why would that be interesting?

Comment: @MartinR I come up with this inequality solving https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2176571/if-ab-1-then-a4b2b4a2-leq1 .

Comment: Note that you can reduce this to a single-variable inequality if you divide by $y^r$ and set $u=x/y$. In other words: Without loss of generality $x > y =1$.

Comment: @MartinR What about $r$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This seems to be true*

Considering the function $$f(x,y)=rx^{r-1}\left(\sqrt{xy}-y\right)-(x^{r}-y^{r})$$

**Part 1**

Let $y=k x$ with $0 < k <1$.

$$f(x,k x)=g(x)=\left(k^r-k r+\sqrt{k} r-1\right) x^r$$ So, to have $g(x)>0$ for any value of $k$ and $r<0$ it remains to show that
$$h(r)=k^r-k r+\sqrt{k} r-1 >0$$
$$h'(r)=k^r \log (k)-k+\sqrt{k}\qquad \text{and} \qquad h''(r)=k^r \log ^2(k) ~~> ~~0$$
$$h'(r)=0 \implies r_*=\frac{1}{\log (k)}\log \left(-\frac{\sqrt{k}-k}{\log (k)}\right) > 0$$ So, $h(r)$ is a decreasing function which is always positive and then $f(x,kx) >0$.

**Part 2**

If, as commented by @Martin R, we make $y=1$, we have
$$f(x,1)=g(x)=1-x^{r-1} \left(x-r \sqrt{x}+r\right)$$
$$g'(x)=\frac{1}{2} r \Big[(2 r-1) \sqrt{x}-2 x+2-2r\Big] x^{r-2}$$

$g'(x)$ cancels for two values of $x$
$$x_\pm=\frac{1}{8} \left(4 r^2-12 r+9 \pm(2 r-1) \sqrt{4 r^2-20 r+17}\right)$$ but $x_+ <1$.

But $g(x_-) >0$ as well as $g''(x_-)$.

Comment: Good Claude have you an idea for the second question ?

Comment: @ErikSatie. If what I wrote is correct, since $h(r)>0$ and $r<0$, $(g(x) \sim x^r \to 0^+$

Comment: Ok that is good thanks .